# Azure AKS Application Gateway 502 bad gateway

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have been following the tutorial here:
[MS Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-new#code-try-4)

This is fine. However deploying a local config file I get a "502 Gate Way" error. This config has been fine and works as expected.

Can anyone see anything obvious with this: At this point I don't know where to start.

I am trying to achieve using the ingress controller that is Application gateway. Then add deployments and apply additional ingress rules

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: one-api
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    imageregistry: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0"
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: one-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: one-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: one-api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: one-api
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: one-api
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: two-api
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    imageregistry: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0"
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: two-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: two-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: two-api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: two-api
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: two-api
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: strata-2022
  labels:
    app: my-docker-apps
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: one-api
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /two-api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: two-api
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Output of: `kubectl describe ingress strata-2022`

```
Name:             strata-2022
```

Labels:           app=my-docker-apps
Namespace:        default
Address:          51.142.191.83
Ingress Class:    
Default backend:  
Rules:
Host        Path  Backends

---

- ```
        /          one-api:80 (10.224.0.15:80,10.224.0.59:80,10.224.0.94:80)
        /two-api   two-api:80 (10.224.0.13:80,10.224.0.51:80,10.224.0.82:80)
  ```

Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
Events:

`kubectl describe ingress`

```
Name:             strata-2022
Labels:           app=my-docker-apps
Namespace:        default
Address:          51.142.191.83
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /          one-api:80 (10.224.0.15:80,10.224.0.59:80,10.224.0.94:80)
              /two-api   two-api:80 (10.224.0.13:80,10.224.0.51:80,10.224.0.82:80)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
Events:       <none>
```

Commands used to create AKS using Azure CLI.

`az aks create -n myCluster -g david-tutorial --network-plugin azure --enable-managed-identity -a ingress-appgw --appgw-name testApplicationGateway --appgw-subnet-cidr "10.225.0.0/16" --generate-ssh-keys`

// Get credentials and switch to this context

`az aks get-credentials -n myCluster -g david-tutorial`

// This line is from the tutorial -- this works as expected

//kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/master/docs/examples/aspnetapp.yaml

// This is what i ran. It works locally

`kubectl apply -f nano new-deploy.yaml`

// Get address

`kubectl get ingress`

`kubectl get configmap`

Comment: could you share some additional details? it would be great if you can add the output of the `kubectl describe ingress strata-2022` command; if possible, it would be great if you can also add the status of your pods & services, just to ensure they are properly configured

Comment: @vladzam output added

Comment: thanks for providing the additional output; when running `kubectl describe ingress`, do you see anything similar to this line? `Normal   SuccessfullyReconciled  16s (x2 over 29s)  ingress  Successfully reconciled` this would indicate the Ingress resource was properly configured - could you also please share your VNET configuration and what are the steps you took to create the AKS cluster and Gateway resources? did you use the exact same commands as from the tutorial?

Comment: @vladzam, no. I just ran `kubectl describe ingress` nothing even remotely similar. I've added the output to the bottom of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried recreating the same setup on my end, and I could identify the following issue right after running the same `az aks` create command: All the instances in one or more of your backend pools are unhealthy.
[image: All the instances in one or more of your backend pools are unhealthy]

Since this appeared to indicate that the backend pools are unreachable, it was strange at first so I tried to look at the logs of one of the pods based on the hello-app images you were using and noticed this right away:

```
> kubectl logs one-api-77f9b4b9f-6sv6f
2022/08/12 00:22:04 Server listening on port 8080
```

Hence, my immediate thought was that maybe in the Docker image that you are using, nothing is configured to listen on port `80`, which is the port you are using in your kubernetes resources definition.

After updating your Deployment and Service definitions to use port `8080` instead of `80`, everything worked perfectly fine and I started getting the following response in my browser:

```
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: one-api-d486fbfd7-pm8kt
```

Below you can find the updated YAML file that I used to successfully deploy all the resources:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: one-api
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    imageregistry: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0"
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: one-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: one-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: one-api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: one-api
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: one-api
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: two-api
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    imageregistry: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0"
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: two-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: two-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: two-api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: two-api
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: two-api
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: strata-2022
  labels:
    app: my-docker-apps
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: one-api
                port:
                  number: 8080
          - path: /two-api
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: two-api
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. Not only the fix but your process you went through. D

Comment: anytime! happy I could help