# AZURE AKS: why network Policy not working?

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I have an kubernetes cluster (AKS) within azure, With Application Gateway Ingress Controller.

I deployed on it, wordpress helm release. I Would like to enable ingress traffic only from Application Gateway ingress controller pod which is in `kube-system`

So, my `values.yml` look like :

```
# I paste only NetworkPolicy part
networkPolicy:
  enabled: true
  ingress:
    enabled: true
  ingressRules:
    customRules:
      - from:
          - namespaceSelector:
              matchLabels:
                kubernetes.io/metadata.name: kube-system
            podSelector:
              matchLabels:
                app: ingress-appgw
```

However when i deploy a release, the wordpress its self works fine. But i can not access to it via `<Application_Gateway_Ingress_Controller_PublicIP>`

On my Azure Portal, when i go Application Gateway resource i got the following messages:

**Image1:**
[image]

**Image2:**
[image]

But when i remove Network Policy part from `values.yml`, the AGIC become healthy!

Any Help please ?

Thank you in adavance!

Answer (score 0):

This error mentions as you don't have any healthy backend pools, try to add healthy probes as below. ***This will continuously monitor your backend pools for the health status, and it will update the application gateway. App gateway will only send traffic to healthy backend pools*** and refresh

[image]

[image]

After adding healthy probes and refresh it takes few minutes for updating these and try to access the application gateway and then *if you received invalid hostname error try to change the setting as below in advance*

[image]

Check out this [So thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73321328/azure-aks-application-gateway-502-bad-gateway) by Vladam for some pointers.

---

Alternately, try to develop a network policy that blocks all traffic. Create a file named as `backend-policy.yaml` and use the below manifest to block all incoming traffic to the pod:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: backend-policy
  namespace: development
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
      role: backend
  ingress: []
```

Reference:

[Troubleshoot backend health issues in Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting)

[Secure pod traffic with network policy - Azure Kubernetes Service | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-network-policies#create-and-apply-a-network-policy)

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue, using seemingly correct namespaceSelector (as above) and/or podSelector in `from` clause of my ingress rule of the NetworkPolicy,
the communication to the health probes is still blocked unless I open it by using empty `from` clause allowing traffic from any source:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: argocd-autopilot
    devTeam: buildchain-and-developer-experience
    gitopstool: argocd
  name: argocd-applicationset-controller-network-policy
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  ingress:
  - from: []
    ports:
    - port: 7000
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-applicationset-controller
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

which result in a working, although modified NetworkPolicy, compared to the [netpol from argocd public source](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/manifests/ha/install.yaml#L23403):

```sh
kubectl -n argocd describe netpol/argocd-applicationset-controller-network-policy
Name:         argocd-applicationset-controller-network-policy
Namespace:    argocd
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Spec:
  PodSelector:     app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-applicationset-controller
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: 7000/TCP
    To Port: 8080/TCP
    From: <any> (traffic not restricted by source)
  Not affecting egress traffic
  Policy Types: Ingress
```