# ingress nginx redirect too many times

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have deployed an app in aks with below ingress

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cas-ingress
  namespace: cas
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: 'false'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN";
      more_set_headers "X-Xss-Protection: 0";
      more_set_headers "Referrer-Policy: use strict-origin-when-cross-origin";
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 10m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: sha1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
    
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - afg-cas-preprod.mocomtest.com
      secretName: mozcomtest-tls
  rules:
    - host: afg-cas-preprod.mocomtest.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: cas-server
                port:
                  number: 6443
```

when i hit the url "afg-cas-preprod.mocomtest.com/auth" , it show the error
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You needed to tell the nginx-ingress-controller that you were expecting HTTPS connections. Add nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS" in the annotations of the yaml file.

Comment: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"  added in ingress and it shows 502

Comment: 502  may be due to ports and firewall rules, meanwhile check this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73321328) for the solution.

Comment: did you try to change the ports?

Comment: @AKHILKUMAR Could you share output of `curl -v https://afg-cas-preprod.mocomtest.com/auth` ?